# Hide ~$ files in folder

Tags: excel

Am running Cerberus-FTP as cloud file server for storing a ton of excel files.
Many users work from this server and this creates allot of ~$files which are automaticly created on opening of an word or excel file.

However, if the subject is being changed, it wont delete it self but will just stay there in the folder as ~$file.xlsm 1 kb file.
We can delete these files af course. However it looks messy and I dont want to manage a ton folders to manually delete theses files.

The famous show or hide function doesn't work, has nothing todo with that.
I think of setting up an custom attribute to simply hide these files on opening? Is there any method of hiding these or store it into an different folder, instead of the root folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into the completely the wrong direction but found below solution

hide everything starting with ~$
use this from command line: `ATTRIB +H /s /d C:\~$*`